# Why can't I call rspec let(:variables) with symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am learning Rspec using rails. I have looked up the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) at relish app and it makes no mention why.

```
RSpec.describe "mighty morphin power rangers" do
  let(:power_rangers) { [:red, :blue, :pink, :yellow, :black]}

  it "have 5 rangers" do
    expect(power_rangers.size).to eql(5)
  end

  context "the second season" do
    it "enter white ranger!" do
      power_rangers << :white
      expect(power_rangers.size).to eql(6)
      expect(power_rangers).to eql([:red, :blue, :pink, :yellow, :black, :white])
    end
  end
end
```

My question is, when I declared `let(:power_rangers)` for the first time, it uses symbol (hence `:`). But when I do the test, for example, `expect(power_rangers.size).to eql(5)`, it returns error if I do `expect(:power_rangers.size).to eql(5)`. Error says:

```
  1) mighty morphin power rangers have 5 rangers
     Failure/Error: expect(:power_rangers.size).to eql(5)

       expected: 5
            got: 13
```

If I declared the variable as a symbol in the beginning, shouldn't I need to call it as a symbol at any time? Why does it say it got 13 when I use `:power_rangers` and return the expected value/ passes when I use `power_rangers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring the following:

`let(:power_rangers) { [:red, :blue, :pink, :yellow, :black]}`

You are essentially telling `rspec` to define a method `power_rangers` with `[:red, :blue, :pink, :yellow, :black]` as its body.

Later when you call `power_rangers` then it returns `[:red, :blue, :pink, :yellow, :black]`.

So calling:

`expect(power_rangers.size).to eql(6)`

is essentially same as:

`expect([:red, :blue, :pink, :yellow, :black].size).to eql(6)`

But by calling:

`expect(:power_rangers.size).to eql(6)`

You are saying:

`expect(13).to eql(6)`

Because `:power_rangers.size` is 13, it is the number of characters of the symbol `:power_rangers`.

Comment: That makes sense! I was wondering where `13` comes from. When you say "telling `rspec` to define a method `power_rangers`...", can you define method? Thanks for the explanation, it already cleared up a few things!

Comment: Thats the metaprogramming behind `let` method of `rspec` that defines the method.